# Gtk style/gtkrc related question

Tags: gtk

I trying to set separate style for particular widgets, like for one button with different style and another one with other style. this style will be specified in gtkrc file. I tried following stuff but it did not work.

```
In gtkrc file:
    style "my-style" 
    {
         engine "pixmap"
         {
              ...
         }
         ...
    }
    class "my_widget" style "my-style"
```

And while creating widget i have given the widget name specified in gtkrc file.

```
In code:

       button = gtk_button_new();
       gtk_widget_set_name( button, "my_widget");
       gtk_widget_show( button );
```

but this stuff is not working out i am not able to see given style to that particular widget. Is this a right way of doing this? what is worn in it?

Thanks,
PP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not right: you **must** read [the documentation](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/gtk-Resource-Files.html), particulary the *Pathnames and patterns* section.

It is not an option if you plan to use resource files seriously...

Comment: The link is dead.  Try a google search with 


    file:gtk-Resource-Files.html


for another copy.